# Can´t access to Default NewForm to edit content

Tags: sharepoint-online

I want to edit Default NewForm.aspx to add JS to it with Script Editor but I can´t do it because when I clic on it I get error:
[image]

[image]

Why I can´t edit it? It always throw me that error so I can access to add Script Editor. Regards

Comment: Do you have any custom code in the new form ?

Comment: My site have custom Layout , but about list I just create it, but I don´t modified nothing of code there because I can´t access it @M.Qassas

Comment: Could you try the same functionality to another list?

Comment: I create a new list and I added to WebPage but I get same result when trying to access to NewForm @M.Qassas

Comment: Go to site content > click on your list > From the above ribbon try to use the form web part from this place!

Comment: Did you get the same error with the below workaround ?

Comment: I can use it into site content > click on your list, and yes I have the same error with below workaround @M.Qassas

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65151/discussion-between-m-qassas-and-ledwing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unexpected error is an ambiguous error, But what I think you are using the `New experiences for lists` and the **Form Web Parts** is only available in the `Classic experiences`

**So try to do the following:**

- Go to site content > open your list.
- Go to list Setting > Advanced Setting.
- Scroll down to List experience.

[image]

- If the `New Experience` is checked so you will not be able to use **Form Web Parts** So Check Classic Experience to can open your forms in edit mode.

---

**See also**

- [Switch the default experience for lists or document libraries from new or classic](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Switch-the-default-experience-for-lists-or-document-libraries-from-new-or-classic-66dac24b-4177-4775-bf50-3d267318caa9)
- [Differences between classic and new experiences for lists and document libraries](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Differences-between-classic-and-new-experiences-for-lists-and-document-libraries-30e1aab0-a5cc-4363-b7f2-09e2ae07d4dc)

Comment: M-Qassas I have troubles with something about this , are you there?

Comment: I'm here, I invited you to the same chat room

Comment: Take a look at my New question please https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/225028/69830

Comment: @Ledwing sorry for delay reply I just saw your comment and I have answered the new question, Hope it help!