# Settings bar or ribbon disappear when load NewForm or EditForm

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, ribbon

I have a list into main view, problem is when I want to change settings of NewForm.aspx or EditForm.aspx. When I clic like in image:

[image]

above settings bar disappear like this:

[image]

Someone know what is wrong there? is something about permissions? I try to open it in another WebBrowser like IE and Firefox but I'm getting same results. Regards

Comment: Same issue on my side - I tried IE and Edge but still no Ribbon in edit forms:/

Comment: But is not SharePoint issue, is something about configuration because I have two different sites, in one site it load correctly but into this one not. @rafter13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I don't think it's a permission issue. In the permission issue, the ribbon will be shown but some options will be disabled with a warning message as shown below:

[image]

In your case, may be the ribbon is hidden. So try to check the `Setting` menu and click on the `Show Ribbon` option as shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but I was having trouble with this too and after scouring the web looking for an answer all morning, I accidentally stumbled on the answer myself.

I had to go to the Setting menu (the gear icon) and chose "Edit Page". It then then reloaded the page including the ribbon for me.

Maybe this will help someone in the future.